# What does TypeKind.Submission and TypeKind.Module mean in the Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.TypeKind enum?

Tags: c#, roslyn, roslyn-code-analysis

I've encountered TypeKind enum:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.codeanalysis.typekind?view=roslyn-dotnet

Could anybody explain what does TypeKind.Submission mean? What types are "interactive submissions"?

Also what is TypeKind.Module? What is module type?

Comment: In VS: View > Other Windows > C# Interactive.  That's where you create a TypeKind.Submission type.  TypeKind.Module is specific to VB.NET code and implements the Module keyword.  Pretty similar to a static class in C#.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Module` is the VB keyword for a `static class`.

In C#, it [becomes a `class`](http://source.roslyn.io/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp/SymbolDisplay/SymbolDisplayVisitor.Types.cs,552).

---

`TypeKind.Submission` refers to the auto-generated class used to hold variables in interactive sessions. ([src](http://source.roslyn.io/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp/Binder/ForEachLoopBinder.cs,878))

Comment: So the TypeKind.Module refers to the VB module or to “assembly” module?

Comment: @SENya: To the VB `Module`.